# How to find the minimum positive integer in a list of lists in O(n)?

Tags: python, big-o

I am trying to write a program in python that consumes a list that contains as many inner lists as the length of the outer list. For example,

```
L = [[-10, -9,    99,   100],
     [ -6, -3,   100,   101],
     [ -1,  0,  1000,  1010],
     [ -1, 10, 10000, 24852]]
```

and it outputs the smallest positive integer. It outputs -1 is there if all elements are negative or 0. The output for the list above would be 10. The elements are also always sorted in ascending order, so both the rows and the columns are sorted in ascending order. What this means is that if you look at any row or any column, it will be sorted from left-to-right and top-to-bottom, respectively.

The issue is I have to do this in O(n) efficiency (n referring to the length of the outer list) but every solution I come up with involves nested loops and thus the efficiency becomes O(n^2).

How can I achieve this in O(n) efficiency in python?

Edit: I have written the following code which works for some cases but doesn't work for others

```
def min_positive(L): 
i = 0
n = len(L)
j = len(L) - 1
min_pos = L[0][j]
while ( i < n and j >= 0 ): 
    if (L[i][j] < min_pos and L[i][j] > 0): 
        min_pos = L[i][j]
    if (L[i][j] >= min_pos): 
        j = j - 1 
    i = i + 1
if min_pos <= 0:
    min_pos = -1 
return min_pos
```

This works for the following list

```
L = [[-10, -9,    99,   100],
 [ -6, -3,   100,   101],
 [ -1,  0,  1000,  1010],
 [ -1, 10, 10000, 24852]]
```

but doesn't work for the list

```
L = [[-10, -9,    99,   100],
     [ -6, -3,   100,   101],
     [ -1,  0,  1000,  1010],
     [ 1, 10, 10000, 24852]]
```

ie. output should be 1 but it's still 10
Feel like I'm close so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you consider `n` in this case? The total number of integers or the number of elements in the outer list?

Comment: "but every solution I come up with involves nested loops and thus the efficiency becomes O(n^2)" - algorithmic complexity isn't an exercise in counting loops. It's based on *how much work your algorithm does*.

Comment: If the elements are in ascending order then you only need to check the first element.

Comment: @AzizSonawalla n is the length of the list, so in this case, it would be 4

Comment: @Aplet123: No, because of negative elements.

Comment: What, *exactly*, do you mean by "The elements are also always sorted in ascending order."? "Sorted" is a one-dimensional property, while your input is two-dimensional. Are both rows and columns in ascending order?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica  Yes each row and column are in ascending order

Comment: Hint: there's a sort of staircase-shaped border between negative and positive elements. Follow the border.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: We have the ordering guarantees we need: "both the rows and the columns are sorted in ascending order".

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Could you have a look at the code above that I have written?

Comment: `L[i][j] >= min_pos` is the wrong condition for going left, and you're often not going far enough left.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica So what should the condition be?

Comment: The condition should be to keep moving left as long as you're on a positive value, i.e. `L[i][j] > 0`. You'll want an `else:` after moving left, so that you aren't unconditionally moving down on *every* iteration. Actually, your original code was very close to working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a worst case, `O(M + N)` solution where M is the number of rows and N is the number of columns.

```py
L = [[-10, -9,    99,   100],
     [ -6, -3,   100,   101],
     [ -1,  0,  1000,  1010],
     [ -1, 10, 10000, 24852]]

def get_least_positive(list_of_lists):
    minimum = float("inf")

    # start from top right
    row = 0
    column = len(list_of_lists[0]) - 1

    # follow the staicase
    while row < len(list_of_lists) and column >= 0:
        elem = list_of_lists[row][column]
        if elem > 0:
            minimum = min(minimum, elem)
            column -= 1
        else:  # found Negative, go to next row.
            row += 1

    return minimum if minimum != float('inf') else -1


print(get_least_positive(L))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for :[[-10, -9, 10, 100, 110]
[-9,  -8, -7, 9, 100],
] I suppose it isn't a square matrix but you can see the breakdown of the algorithm in those two rows, if all the remaining values in other rows are negative you end up with the answer 10 instead of 9.

Comment: @DavidOldford: Your input is invalid. Elements need to be ascending along columns as well as rows.

Comment: It was based on a different interpretation of the criteria given. There are multiple columns within rows that are lists and multiple rows that are lists in one larger list. My example works if you're talking about sorting all the columns by running sort on each row and sorting all the rows by running sort on the list containing all the rows. I suppose this wasn't what was intended.

Answer (score 1):

An *O(n)* idea is to start at the top-right corner, move left when you are on a positive value, and move down otherwise. For a square array, this visits at most 2*n - 1 indices, because the algorithm never backtracks. List subscription is *O(1)*, so we are linear time complexity and constant space complexity.

```
def min_linear(L):
    n_rows = len(L)
    n_cols = len(L[0])
    row, col = 0, n_cols - 1  # start a the top-right corner
    best = L[-1][-1]  # initialized to the maximum element
    if best <= 0:
        # no positive elements
        return -1
    while col >= 0 and row < n_rows:
        val = L[row][col]
        if val > 0:
            best = min(val, best)
            col -= 1  # move left
        else:
            row += 1  # move down
    return best
```

Answer (score 0):

I can provide some basic idea:

**1.start from bottom right**

since it's sorted in both *row* and *column*, meaning bottom right is biggest, and if bottom right is negative, then rest of those is negative.

**2.make a path walking solution**

It means you would like to walk down(descending) until you meet negative, which you then move another direction. Utility the advantage of ascending, you can walk to min pos without checking middle items, because they are obviously larger. By doing so, you can also skip negative value too.